# Distance calculation with v.net.path in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network-analyst, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

I have 3 layers: origin and destination point shapefiles and network line shapefiles. I want to calculate the shortest path on the network between the origin (250 features) and destinations (20 features) by using the v.net.path command. I don`t understand what the CENTRE POINT LAYER and NAME OF FILE CONTAINING START AND END POINTS is (as indicated on the photo) and I couldn`t find a clear description about it. Could someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at te manual page of v.net.path: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.path.html#example

Comment: Then check here: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Vector_Network_Analysis_Tool