# v.net path syntax question

Tags: qgis

i am referig to this post [How to use v.net.path algorithm on QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450909/how-to-use-v-net-path-algorithm-on-qgis/459873#459873).

I have an additional question regarding the syntax:
Lets say I have 4 nodes ID: 1,2,3,4
they are connected to a network (done with v.net)
I want to find the shortest path between the Points 1 and 4 e.g.
Is the right syntax than:
1 1 4
?
Because I get an format error with this.

Comment: The format looks right, but the numbers must refer to GRASS **cat** values. I don't know what the node ID values are that you refer to. Check you category values with `v.category ... option=print`

Comment: 'cat' column is the unique identifier, right? or am I misunderstanding this. In general I have 1) node layer and 2) network layer connecting the nodes. Shortest path method only gives me the option to select coordinates but not the names of the nodes. I want so select start and end node by name and additionally want to know  the nodes which are on the shortest path